# How to authentication sharepoint onpremise by Azure AD using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, authentication, azure-ad, authorization

I am using CSOM to connect to SharePoint on-premises site. I want to authenticate SharePoint site by using Azure AD, but it returns 401 error.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is your SharePoint on-premises farm linked to a local AD or Azure AD?

Comment: Hello @CallumCrowley, thanks for your comment, My Farm linked to local AD, my code follow this acticle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard, but when i get token from Azure and set Authorizetion to my site like:
var context = new ClientContext(web);

            context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
            {
               e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
            };
But context not authorize.

Comment: If your on-premises is linked to local AD, then you can't use Azure AD to authenticate with your SharePoint farm.

Comment: I config my site by follow this acticle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial, it work, but i authentication by CSOM it not work

Comment: Ahhh I see, I'm not sure how you go about authenticating in that scenario

Comment: My Site can access by web browser and mobile application, on web browser i config single sign-on via azure AD, access by web work well. Mobile application acceess via ASP.net web api using CSOM, but it cannot authorizire the user. Can you suggest me some solution @CallumCrowley

Comment: I'm not sure what the solution would be.